# Why strpos PHP not work with fsockopen response?

Tags: php, strpos

Why `strpos PHP` not work with fsockopen response ?

When load this code. This code will be requests `sdgsgsdgsfsdfsd.ca` to `whois.cira.ca` server and find text `Domain status: available` with `strpos PHP` if found  it's will be echo

```
{"domain":"sdgsgsdgsfsdfsdca","availability":"available"}
```

but if not found text. It's will be echo

```
{"domain":"sdgsgsdgsfsdfsdca","availability":"TAKEN"}
```

In this case `found text` but still echo

```
{"domain":"sdgsgsdgsfsdfsdca","availability":"TAKEN"}
```

How can i do ?

```
<?php
$server = "whois.cira.ca";
$response = "Domain status: available";
showDomainResult(sdgsgsdgsfsdfsd.ca,$server,$response); 

function checkDomain($domain_check,$server,$findText)
{
    $con = fsockopen($server, 43);
    if (!$con) return false;
    fputs($con, $domain_check."\r\n");
    $response = ' :';
    while(!feof($con)) 
    {
        $response .= fgets($con,128); 
    }
    echo $response."<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>";
    fclose($con);
    if (strpos($response, $findText))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false; 
    }
}

function showDomainResult($domain_check,$server,$findText)
{
    if (checkDomain($domain_check,$server,$findText))
    {
        class Emp 
        {
            public $domain = "";
            public $availability = "";
        }
        $e = new Emp();
        $e->domain = $domain_check;
        $e->availability = "available";
        echo json_encode($e);
    }
    else
    {
        class Emp 
        {
            public $domain = "";
            public $availability = "";
        }
        $e = new Emp();
        $e->domain = $domain_check;
        $e->availability = "TAKEN";
        echo json_encode($e);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using strpos wrong, if the string START with what you're searching for, it will return int(0), which is "kinda false" by PHP's definition. explicitly check for `false`, like this

`return false!==strpos($response, $findText);`

and make sure you're using `!==` not `!=`

and as a rule of thumb, never use loose comparison operators in PHP if you can avoid it, hilarious bugs can occur if you do: https://3v4l.org/tT4l8